# remove tuple from list if element is contained within it

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of players and a list of tuples

```
players = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
shortlist = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e',)]
```

There are two pairs and a single tuple.
I want each player to choose one tuple from the shortlist, however they cannot choose the tuple which they are in, if they are in the shortlist.

My current attempt:

```
for person in players:
    for item in shortlist:
        if person in item:
            new_list = shortlist.remove(item)
            their_choice = random.choices(new_list, k=1)
            df[person] = their_choice
```

But I am just getting empty values in the dataframe. I think there must be a way to do this using list comprehension but I can't quite figure it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: "remove" works inplace, it doesn't return a list but modifies "shortlist".

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to modify the list whilst looping over it (e.g. with `remove`).

Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

```
import random
choices = []
for person in players:
    eligible_items = [item for item in shortlist if person not in item]
    their_choice = random.choices(eligible_items)[0]
    choices.append(their_choice)
```

Or in one big list comprehension?

```
[
    random.choices([item for item in shortlist if person not in item])[0]
    for person in players
]
```

Answer (score 0):

modifying your code a little the second loop can be done in a list comprehension, so something like this should work:

```
for person in players:
    df[person] = random.choices(shortlist, [person not in choice for choice in shortlist])
```

what is happening here  is we assign a weight to each choice in the second argument of choices. The weights are calculated using list comprehension for every person and they are `False` for the choice containing the person and `True` for the others. Luckily `random.choices()` accepts True False list as weights or conversion to 0 and 1 would be needed.